# Не получается установить title для toolBar

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Есть toolBar:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="#03A9F4" />
```

В Activity устанавливаю его:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

и хочу изменить Title:

```
toolbar.setTitle("BlaBla");
```

Результат - toolBar на экран выводится, но мой Title не устанавливается, вместо BlaBla в нем названия приложения выводит.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить **title** таким способом:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("BlaBla");
```

Comment: спасибо, работает) не подскажете как изменить цвет текста в Title?

Comment: @Денис а метода setTitleTextColor() разве нет?`https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setTitleTextColor(int)`

Comment: ссылка недоступна почему-то у меня. не могли бы вы установить красный цвет для Title. Пробывал так `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Bla Bla").setTitleTextColor();` - ошибка

Comment: @Денис ну так что за ошибка? метод `setTitleTextColor()` вообще доступен?

Comment: Делал так `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Bla Bla").setTitleTextColor(Color.RED);` Eclipse ругается - `Cannot invoke setTitleTextColor(int) on the primitive type void`

Comment: Сделал через стили цвет текста. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Денис ну так эт может и не билдер, `getSupportActionBar().setTitleTextColor(Color.RED);`